# How to prove this programming puzzle problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Initially you are given $3$ numbers $(a,b,c)$. Find two numbers with the smallest difference, and add the difference to the multiset. Keep repeating this operation until difference is zero. Numbers can be up to $10^{18}$.
Program needs to output how many iteration is needed for algorithm to finish.

Example: If initial numbers is (234, 532, 245)

First move: Add (245-234) -> (234, 532, 245, 11)

Second move: Same -> (234, 532, 245, 11, 11)

Third move: Add zero. Finished.

At first I thought this will require some clever algorithm because it needs to give answer within 0.5s. But it turns out that for most random test case with numbers up to $10^{18}$, it just needs around $3$-$5$ moves, so pure simulation works just fine.

My question: Is there a closed form formula for this, or maybe a way to prove upper bound on number of moves needed given some initial configuration (like the worst possible case that results in most number of iterations) Thanks.

Original source: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1777. No need to read problem description, just skip to input and output sample.

Comment: $245-234=11\;\;$

Comment: I don't know if there is somewhere a formula for this, but if you think about it a little the pattern is pretty clear.
@lulu to the rescue :p

Comment: @lulu ah yes sorry stupid mistake. Edited

Comment: What's  the worst case you've seen?  (I mean, what three numbers took the longest to halt?)

Comment: Can you post the worst case you found?  I mean the one that took the greatest number of steps.

Comment: I don't have the simulation code right now. But if I remember right it's somewhere around 15 step.

Comment: "At first I thought this will require some clever algorithm"  Some clever algorithm to do what?  You forgot to state what it is you are trying to actually do!  Prove that it always terminates? (that's obvious isn't it since each turn will add a smaller or equal pile; equal pile terminates; smaller pile can only be done a finite number of times).  Calculate number of steps without actually doing it?  Showing that it can/can not take more than 5 steps?

Comment: I apologize if my question is poorly worded. What I mean by needing "clever algorithm" is: at first I thought solving this problem with just simulation is not possible; it will take too long (in source you can see that the time limit is only 0.5s). You will need some clever pruning or formula or something. But it turns out pure simulation works just fine and most cases doesn't take that much iteration to finish. And I asked here if anyone can help me prove the upper bound on number of iterations given some initial configuration.

Comment: I have edited the questions adding more details. If there is still ambiguity or parts that are poorly worded I welcome feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can make it as long as desired. Take $3$ consecutive Fibonacci numbers, $F_n, F_{n+1}, F_{n+2}.$  The smallest difference is $F_{n+1}-F_n=F_{n-1}.$
Then we add $F_{n-2}$ etc.

I think this is probably the worst case in the sense that it gives the longest number of steps for a given initial difference.  So far, I don't see how to prove that.  Something to do with the Euclidean algorithm, perhaps.

Comment: If this is indeed the worst case scenario, then it makes sense for the algorithm to terminate quickly given the constraint. Since even just the 100th fibonacci number is already much bigger than $10^{18}$. It also makes sense why the worst case doesn't appear in random simulation because it would take a massive coincidence to generate 3 consecutive fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is a "while" kind of algorithm (sorry for the lack of a better term).

The exit condition is that the difference between two numbers is $0$.

The initial set is $(a,b,c)$

Then, while the exit condition is not met, we keep adding the lowest difference amongst elements of the set.

Let's assume we work with relative integers, I think you can see that for any number $n$ we add to the set, $$|n| \le min\{ |a-b|,|a-c|,|b-c| \} = N$$

That is $n \in A, A =\{k\in \mathbb{Z}, -N\le k\le N\} $

And $A$ is a finite set (I'm not sure of the english term, I mean there is a finite number of elements)

So we can deduce that there is a maximum number of steps ($2N$ for relative integers, $N$ for integers) we can do before we introduce the same number twice and that would mean that we meet the exit condition.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but doesn't this just prove that the algorithm will always terminates? Or does this also prove that the algorithm will always terminate in "small" number of steps even for large numbers?

Comment: What I proved was an absolute maximum number of steps relative to the initial lowest difference between the three numbers, in no case does this guarantee a low number of iterations.